# Слова "нет" и "да"

Tags: лексика

Это, скорее, наблюдение, нежели вопрос. Интересно, что почти во всех языках слово "нет" похоже: *нет, нi, no, not, nicht, non и т. д.,* зато слово "да" не повторяется практически ни разу.
Интересно, с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Примеры  не  из  "всех" языков,  а  из  индоевропейских.  Но  вопрос  интересный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сразу же вспомнилось тюркское "нет" -- **йок**. Без буквы "н".

> нет, нi, no, not, nicht, non

not, nicht -- значит "не" в соответственно английском и немецком. А "нет" в этих языках -- "no" и "nein" происходит от сокращённого "ни один".

Вообще сначала скажу, что, как уже заметили в другом ответе, перечисленные слова из индоевропейских языков, т.е. родственных. Считается, что русское "не" очень древнего происхождения, ещё из общего языка-предка, т.н. праиндоевропейского (ПИЕ или лат. буквами PIE).

Немецкое *nein* -- это *ne* + *ein*, т.е. "ни один".

Английское ne + one -- none. Или староанглийское, кажется *nan*, если не ошибаюсь с написанием. Отсюда сокращённое до современного английского слова *no*.

Русское "нет" -- предполагается, что это сокр. "не есть".

Славянские "да" и "так". Кажется (некогда искать подтверждения, пусть меня поправят, если не так вспомнил) от старинного "да будет так", т.е. "пусть будет так".

Германские вариации слова "да" -- "йа", "йеа" и т.п. -- учёные выводят к ПИЕ то ли "йа", то ли "йе".

Comment: >Славянские "да" и "так". Кажется, от старинного "да будет так", т.е. "пусть будет так".

Вот ещё, случайно попалось в словаре на английском , как раз по этой теме.

**Этимология слова yes**

Answer (score 2):

Выскажу свое предположение. "Нет" в разных языках похоже лишь наличием звука "н". Возможно, что очень давно, когда речь только складывалась, люди решили (а может, и неосознанно), что, кивая из стороны в стороны, что ужа раньше означало отрицание, будут издавать звук, похожий на нынешний звук "н". Эта штука встречается и сейчас у детей и не только. Должно быть, поэтому слово "нет" во многих языках имеет звук "н". Со словом "да" такой штуки не происходило.   
Это лишь мое предположение, основанное на моей логике, так что   я могу ошибаться.

Comment: > @Валентин: кивая из стороны в стороны
> 

 - это как?  При отрицании мы мотаем головой "из стороны в сторону", а киваем (двигаем головой вперед-назад) при утверждении. А в некоторых странах (Болгарии, например) при отрицании кивают головой, а при утверждении - мотают.

Comment: да уж, логика весьма зыбкая. 
Язык начал "складываться" во времена неандертальцев, а совпадения касается ПИЕ-общности, которой от силы 10 тысяч лет.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько понимаю, славянские "да", "так", "так есть" и проч. и германские Ja, Je, Yes - родственны на ПИЕ уровне. 
Аналогично и все варианты "нет" в германских, романских и славянских.

С другой стороны, изолированные ПИЕ-языки, например армянский (айвО и вош) и греческий (нэ и Охи), совсем не следуют этому правилу. Особо греческое да=[нэ] показательно.

В целом могу сказать, что "да" менее стабильная частица уже в силу своего значения. Она, видимо, во всех языках мало где используется помимо своей основной функции. А вот "нет" судя по всему везде связано так или иначе с "не", употребление которой гораздо шире. Поэтому историческая стабильность "нет" много выше.

Comment: Интересно.

Ещё вспомнилось по теме. Видел в Евангелии на церковно-славянском. Там есть приблизительно такая фраза, если на русском: 

*"Не клянитесь, но говорите - да да, нет нет". *

Так вот последняя часть этого предложения, где "да" и "нет", на церковно-славянском выглядит так: "Єй єй, ни ни". 

*Єй* (т.е. [йей]) -- современное *да* -- близко по звучанию к ПИЕ *йе*.

Comment: Єй-єй - это не совсем "да", это что-то вроде утвердительно-усилительной частицы, форма єй-єй применялась как замены "клянусь, что так", её дозволялось кпотреблять с именем бога, чего нельзя было делать для "клянусь".

Answer (score 1):

Греки  в  этом  плане  особенно  поперечные - они  не  только  нэ  вместо  да  говорят,  но  и  головой  при  этом  покачивают  вправо-влево.

Comment: Поясните,  пожалуйста,  Фразу : "да"  менее  стабильная  частица  уже  в  силу  своего  значения.  И  то  же  самое  относительно  "нет".

Comment: Вы бы к моему ответы комменты такие писали, в не к своему.

Я имел в виду, что "нет" фонетически более стабильная. Не так подвержена возможными изменениям, как "да". Этот факт подтверждаетя на  родством "нет" в более широком множестве языков. разумеется, это не математически строгое доказательство, а лишь лингвистический анализ дилетанта, но серьезных возражений пока не поступало.

Comment: Я  бы  с  удовольствием  прокомментировал  ваш  ответ,  но  нашёл  как  это  сделать,  кнопка  "комментировать"  нашлась  только  под  моим  ответом.  Не  могу разобраться, как  на  этом  форуме  обращаться  к  какому-нибудь  из  участников,  хоть  вижу  такие  обращения.  Может  подскажете.  Относительно  моего  вопроса,  то  тема  к  сожалению  осталась  нераскрытой. Нужны  примеры.  Как,  например,  связывается  Фонетическая  стабильность  и  значение ?

Comment: Читайте :  не нашёл...

Comment: >Не могу разобраться, как на этом форуме 

От репутации зависит. Для новичков, у которых мало очков репутации, почти ничего нельзя. Для создания комментария у Вас должно быть от 50 очков. А Вас сейчас только 33. Подробнее -- справка по форуму.

http://russ.hashcode.ru/faq/#heading13

Comment: Значит, надежда  есть.  Это  радует.

Comment: Вспомнил ещё такую штуку. Когда у меня было совсем мало репутации, то можно было написать ответ. А под ответом (кажется, когда под ним ещё нет комментариев) можно выбрать, вроде бы в меню "ещё" - "Преобразовать ответ в комментарий". И потом выбрать в комментарий к которому ответу. У меня так получалось делать.

:-) Не стоит благодарностей, но можно "плюс" мне поставить.

И ещё. В репутацию идут те плюсы, которые ставятся за ответ, но не за комментарий. Плюсы за комментарий в репутацию не добавляются.

Comment: Не совсем правильно Вы делаете. Вы выбрали "наградить". Таким образом Вы награждаете кого-то, например, 2-мя очками в репутацию, а у Вас эти 2 очка вычитаются из Вашей репутации. 

Лучше выбрать слева ответа кнопку, где нарисована рука с пальцем вверх (со всплывающей надписью "мне нравится это сообщение"). Тогда Вы добавляете понравившемуся участнику сразу 10 очков, а у Вас из репутации ничего не отнимается.

Жму эту кнопку возле Вашего ответа, чтобы возместить Вам потерянные очки :). Я сам так поначалу растратил очки репутации.

Comment: Если вы награждаете, ничего у  вас не минусуется.